# In unity, how do I rotate a vector in relation to the player?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, vector, linear-algebra

I am making a radar script in a unity FPS game project I am making for class. I already have a working example of a radar script that works in relation to the player's position. However the rotation is in relation within the world map, not the player's view.

In code I have it kinda like this (not actually my code, as I don't have it with me right now, but basically the same algorithm)

```
if (isPlayerInViewRange(otherPlayer[i]){
    //these are both normalized Vector
    dir = getDirectionFromPosition(player, otherPlayer);
    dir = rotateDirectionInRelationshipToPlayer(player, dir); //problem here
    dir = new Vector3(dir.x, dir.z, 0);

    dir.Scale(MapToRadarPosition, 0, MapToRadarPosition);
    radarDot[i] = dir;
    radarDot[i].setActive(true);
} else {
    radarDot[i].setActive(false);
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing, I feel like I am missing some obvious function to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Transform.TransformDirection()](http://docs.unity3d.ru/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html) method where Transform is your player transform.

```
// Calculate the x-axis relative to the camera
camera = Camera.main.transform;
cameraRelativeRight = camera.TransformDirection (Vector3.right);
// Apply a force relative to the camera's x-axis
rigidbody.AddForce (cameraRelativeRight * 10);
```

Comment: I am not using any sort of Camera. Its basically kind of like a halo style radar. Its a simple green circle with white dots indicating players. I am working with Vector3s Directory.

Comment: Blue kindly edited my post with example from Unity documentation, which uses Camera transform for instance. But I advised you using player's Transform. In your code simply refer to this.transform.TransformDirection(dir)